# Making a Conditional Section Play nice with jQgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a web design question (the least of all my development skills)... I have left justified section in my code That I want to remain the same size, and I want my jqGrid's width to fluctuate with the size of the window and with consideration to that left justified section.  I am really terrible at playing around with the document object model.  But this is a function I have that basically allows jqGrid to have a variable width (variable with the the size of the window)

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
            $("#frTable").fluidGrid({ example: "#tempplateInfo", offset: -10 });
        });
        (function ($) {
            jQuery.jgrid.fluid = {
                fluidGrid: function (options) {
                    var grid = $(this);
                    var settings = $.extend({
                        example: grid.closest('.ui-jqgrid').parent(), offset: 0
                    },
                options || {});
                    var width = $(settings.example).innerWidth() + settings.offset; grid.setGridWidth(width);

                }
            }
        })
    (jQuery);
        jQuery.fn.extend({ fluidGrid: jQuery.jgrid.fluid.fluidGrid });
```

I am guessing what I would need to do is add a factor to the innerWidth() function that I call...  Which would need to be the width or the rightmost side of the div...  I am guessing I would need to grab the rightmost side through its id and add it to that.  But I am not certain at all.  Any Jquery guys that would have a better idea?

Comment: Are you having trouble or are you just not sure if this is the best way to do it?

Comment: I am having trouble.  Particularly when I resize a screen.